# Filter selection from multiple dropdown menus

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-select, onchange

I show or hide a `div` with `class='kd'` when a specific item is selected from a dropdown menu with `id='id_property`':

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("select#id_property").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
            if(optionValue == "G"){
                $(".kd").fadeIn()
            } else{
                $(".kd").hide();
            }
        });
      }).change();
    });
```

Is it possible to filter the selection from multiple dropdown menus and depending on both selections, hide or display an item?

Something like:

```
   $("select#id_property", "select#id_name").change(function(){
       $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            var optionValue1 = $(this).attr("value");
            ...
        });
     });
```

HTML

```html
<select name="property" class="select form-control" required id="id_property">
  <option value="" selected>---------</option>
  <option value="G">G</option>
  <option value="E">E</option>
</select>
<select name="name" class="select form-control" required id="id_name">
  <option value="" selected>---------</option>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
</select>
<div class="form-row row kd">
      <label for="id_some_field" class="form-label ">Some Field</label>
      <input type="text" name="some_field" maxlength="128" class="textinput textInput form-control" id="id_some_field"> 
</div>
```

Comment: could you post your html code here !

Comment: sure, added a sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey , what you have to do is using multiple selector separated with coma `,` ,

```
$("select#id_property , select#id_name").on("change", function() {...})
```

and in the callback function use `$(this).val()` to access value on each input change :

See below snippet :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  let selectValues = [];

  $("select#id_property , select#id_name").on("change", function() {
      var id = $(this).attr("id");
      var optionValue = $(this).val();

      selectValues[id] = optionValue;
      let chars = "";
      for (var key in selectValues) {
        chars += selectValues[key];
    }

    if ( chars.includes("GG") || ( chars.includes("G") && chars.includes("A") ) ) {
        $(".kd").fadeIn()
      } else {
        $(".kd").hide();
      }
    });

  // for startup change 
  $("select#id_property , select#id_name").trigger("change");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

property :
<select name="property" class="select form-control" required id="id_property">
  <option value="" selected>---------</option>
  <option value="G">G</option>
  <option value="E">E</option>
</select><br /><br /> name :
<select name="name" class="select form-control" required id="id_name">
  <option value="" selected>---------</option>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="G">G</option>
</select><br /><br />
<div class="form-row row kd">
  <label for="id_some_field" class="form-label ">Some Field</label>
  <input type="text" name="some_field" maxlength="128" class="textinput textInput form-control" id="id_some_field">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! how would i solve it, if the matching optionValue is not "G" on both selects, but "G" and "A" ?

Comment: Additionally, it should only match if both selections are "G". Currently it matches with one selection or both. I admit that my question was not clear enough.

Comment: @fuser60596 Okey , I didn't want to use id selecors , so , I made it in generale manner , so condition could be changed as you want , see updated answer (store array of id  key then generate string that holds values of those selects )